# Oracle Coherence Cache Object

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

As I do not see much clarification about cache object in Oracle COherence document from Oracle, any one have idea about

1. If Oracle Coherence allows HashMap (Java) Object as a cache Object?
2. If yes, does Oracle Coherence CohQL supports building dynamic filter on HasMap object in Oracle Coherence Cache?

Appreciate in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store a HashMap as a value in Coherence.

Normally though, you'd create a custom value object that holds the data you are working to manage, and one of its properties might be a Map. That way, you can query on the various properties of the value object.

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*